# Firebase Sign In With Email fails without providing an error

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

In my JavaScript Firebase application, I have tried to set up user authentication via email, and at the same time sync user data to Firebase's realtime database. While our Google sign in worked with no problems, the function that makes accounts, `firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);` fails to execute and (annoyingly) does not throw any error messages. Here is the code:
main.js: (The problematic section is submitAcc())

```
var config = {
    apiKey: "censored",
    authDomain: "censored",
    databaseURL: "censored",
    projectId: "censored",
    storageBucket: "censored",
    messagingSenderId: "censored"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);
var database = firebase.database();
function showAccCreate() { //Hides and shows account create button
    var x = document.getElementById("hiddenaccountcreation");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function submitAcc() { //On submit button pressed
    alert("Signing in");
    var email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("passinput").value;
    var username = document.getElementById("usernameinput").value;
    //console.log(email + password +username);
    var user;
    alert("recorded values");
    firebase.auth().createUserAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(function(result) {
        alert("Gets into .then");
        var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        var uidvalue = user.uid;
        console.log(uidvalue);
        console.log(uidvalue);
        alert("User value recorded");
        writeUserDataFromEmailSignin(email, username,uidvalue);
        alert(user.uid);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        alert(error.message);
        console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error.code);
    });
}


//Testing if auth state changes
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
    if (user) {
        alert("User is signed in.");
        document.getElementById("debugtest").innerHTML = "Signed in";
    }
});
function writeUserDataFromEmailSignin(email, name, uuid) { //Writes user data to database if user signs in
    alert("Entered function");
    database.ref('users/' + uuid).set({
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "uid": uuid,
    }).then(function() {
        alert("Completed");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error.code);
    })
}
function showsignin() {
    var x = document.getElementById("hiddensignin");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
function googlesignin() { //Signs people into app via Google
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly");
    firebase.auth().languageCode = 'en';
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        var token = result.credential.accessToken; //Google Auth access token
        var user = result.user; //Contains all user info that Google provided us
        writeToDatabaseFromGoogle(user.email, user.displayName, user.uid, user.photoUrl);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error.code);
    });


}
function writeToDatabaseFromGoogle(email, name, uuid, image_url) { //Writes user data to database from Google signin
    database.ref("users/" + uuid).set({
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        //"imageUrl": image_url,
        "uid": uuid,
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error.code);
    });
}
function signInUser() { //Uses email sign-in so signin to existing account
    var email = document.getElementById("emailreauth");
    var pass = document.getElementById("passreauth");
    // noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function (error) {
        //Handle errors here
        let errorCode = error.code;
        let errorMessage = error.MESSAGE;
        console.log(errorCode);
        console.log(errorMessage);
    });
}
```

and the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--suppress HtmlRequiredLangAttribute -->
       <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase.js"></script>
        <script>
            // Initialize Firebase
            var config = {
                apiKey: "AIzaSyAhglAXFWaJhtvOrfeugAMgJHrBw5CUNEc",
                authDomain: "projectcrosscomm.firebaseapp.com",
                databaseURL: "https://projectcrosscomm.firebaseio.com",
                projectId: "projectcrosscomm",
                storageBucket: "projectcrosscomm.appspot.com",
                messagingSenderId: "412861101382"
            };
            firebase.initializeApp(config);
        </script>
        <!-- Firebase App is always required and must be first -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-app.js"></script>

        <!-- Add additional services that you want to use -->
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-auth.js"></script>
        <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-database.js"></script>


        <!-- Comment out (or don't include) services that you don't want to use -->
        <!-- <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.5/firebase-storage.js"></script> -->


        <script src="main.js" rel="script"></script>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Project Cross Comm!</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="accountcreate" onclick="showAccCreate()">Create your account here!</button>
    <button id="showsignin" onclick="showsignin()">Already have an account?</button>
    <button2 id="googlesignin" onclick="googlesignin()">Sign in with Google</button2>

        <h1>Project Cross Comm!</h1>
        <h2 id="subtitle">
        Welcome to <strong>Project Cross Comm!</strong>
        </h2>
        <img height="200px" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/013/564/doge.jpg" width="260px" alt="If you can't see this image you're a pleb">
        <h2></h2>
        <p id="desc"> Project Cross Comm is a free to use chatting program that runs in your browser. All the chats are encrypted, so no one can read your chats. Enjoy the program and chat away.</p>
        <div id="hiddenaccountcreation">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Account Creation</legend> <!--Create account via email sign-in-->
                    <p>
                        <label for="usernameinput">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="usernameinput" name="createUsername" placeholder="Username">
                    <p>
                        <label for="emailinput">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="emailinput" value="" placeholder="example@example.com" name="createEmail">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="passinput">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="passinput" value="" placeholder="password" name="createPass">
                    </p>
                    <button id="submit" onclick="submitAcc()">SUBMIT</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="hiddensignin">
            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Sign In</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="usernamereauth">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="usernamereauth" value="">
                    <p>
                        <label for="emailreauth">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="emailreauth" value="">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="passreauth">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="passreauth" value="">
                    </p>
                    <button id="signin" onclick="signInUser()">SUBMIT</button>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="getthisblockoutofmygoddamnedway"> <!--Problematic code block that another member of my team put there -->
            <a style = "color: white; "id="link" href="InfoPage.html">Click here for more information.</a>
            <h6></h6>
            <a style = "color: white; "id="link2" href="ChatLayout.html">Click Here To Chat</a>
            <h6></h6>
            <a style = "color: white; "id="link3" href="https://app.termly.io/document/privacy-policy/0ae020d8-ee05-4202-a0c7-d4ff19e8f661">Privacy Policy </a>

        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <p id="debugtest" class="debug">Haven't Been Signed In Yet</p>
        <noscript>Man, sucks for you! We only support modern, functioning browsers. Maybe you should get JavaScript </noscript>
    </footer>
</html>
```

The farthest alert my program gets to is `alert("recorded values");`, no further alerts are executed. Javascript does not throw any errors during the process; the console is empty. Is there any way to find out what's wrong, or even to force Javascript to be more verbose and log its memory every so often?

Comment: As I know, you do not need "then" block. Just check your firebase auth from firebase console. You should see your accounts there.

Comment: I need to get the returned result from the completion of the code. The then block isn't for checking if the account was created, it's giving me access to the UID that I didn't previously have. I'm looking not just to create accounts but to log them in the database. Even so, they aren't created, either. The function does not execute.

Comment: Did you enable the auth settings from firebase console? You need to enable user creation from auth tab in firebase console. There is a option for email accounts. If it is not the case you should be sure if you correctly get sdk. Do you use cdn?

Comment: Yes, auth is enabled and SDK is properly imported. Google Sign In works with no errors, and I got a phone app to do both email and Google auth without problems.

Comment: Let me know if my code works or we can have a look at your complete code and fix it.

Comment: Nope, it still doesn't work. It must be something else in my code, though I don't understand what. I'll add some more comments to it and edit my post.

Comment: @Connor  Paste complete code HTML,JS.. I will try it and help you out. Whatever you have asked me it's working for me. Let me know once edited.

Comment: @Fire-In-D-Hole Edited. I turned the console in my IDE to give verbose errors (apparently it wasn't doing that) and it gets up to just before the function and then... skips it with no error message. It then throws an XHR Failed Loading: POST error and 2 notifications that  XHR finished loading: POST. I also set up a notification to appear when the auth state changed. When I sign in, my auth state changes, and I am considered signed in, _however_, the account is still not created on my Firebase console, nor is data written to the database.

Comment: @Connor Edited my Answer. Your code needs lots of improvements. As per the question, You are only able to reach `recorded values` and I have tested my answer I was able to fetch the users information with `submitAcc()` method. Please test and mark my answer if that works for you.

Comment: It does work, thank you. You're a lifesaver.

Comment: @Connor Good to hear that!!. It would have been solved earlier if you had pasted the complete code before itself. I have a couple of suggestions listed them regarding the code [link](https://pastebin.com/61cAhfQa). pls, check out. In case you need any help you can drop me an email(in my Bio) or raise a question and tag me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Current issue is you are not able to store the Values into the DB with the method `submitAcc()`.This `method` is called when the user creates the account. I have corrected and made some changes please test and let me know if that works for you.

I have added two functions `logout()` and `status()` to understand where the problem is. I'd suggest you remove them.

I have also observed in the method `signInUser()`. You have missed the `.value` to `Email` and `Password` and corrected it.

See below image once the user clicks to Create the Account.I have logged his input to console.

[image]

Database Saving user's info:

[image]

Code

```js
    
  
  var database = firebase.database();


  function showAccCreate() { //Hides and shows account create button
      var x = document.getElementById("hiddenaccountcreation");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  function submitAcc() { //On submit button pressed
      alert("Signing in");
      var email = document.getElementById("emailinput").value;
      var password = document.getElementById("passinput").value;
      var username = document.getElementById("usernameinput").value;
      console.log(email + password +username);
      alert("recorded values");


      firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).then(function(result) {
          alert("Gets into .then");
          var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          var uidvalue = user.uid;
          console.log(uidvalue);
          console.log(uidvalue);
          alert("User value recorded");
          writeUserDataFromEmailSignin(email, username,uidvalue);
          alert(user.uid);
      }).catch(function(error) {
          alert(error.message);
          console.log(error.message);
          console.log(error.code);
      });
  }


  function writeUserDataFromEmailSignin(email, name, uuid) { //Writes user data to database if user signs in
    alert("Entered function");
    database.ref('users/' + uuid).set({
        "name": name,
        "email": email,
        "uid": uuid,
    }).then(function() {
        alert("Completed");
    }).catch(function() {
        console.log(error.message);
        console.log(error.code);
    })
}

  

  function logout()
  {
    firebase.auth().signOut().then(function() {
      // Sign-out successful.
    }).catch(function(error) {
      // An error happened.
    });
  }

  function status()
  {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
      if (user) {
        var emailv =user.email;
        console.log("User is signed in. em ankunav enti "+ emailv);
      } else {
        console.log("No user is signed in."); 
      }
    });
  }
  
  //Testing if auth state changes
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (user) {
      if (user) {
          alert("User is signed in.");
          document.getElementById("debugtest").innerHTML = "Signed in";
      }
      else
      {
        document.getElementById("debugtest").innerHTML = "NOT LOGGED IN ";
      }
  });


  
  function showsignin() {
      var x = document.getElementById("hiddensignin");
      if (x.style.display === "none") {
          x.style.display = "block";
      } else {
          x.style.display = "none";
      }
  }
  
  
  function signInUser() { //Uses email sign-in so signin to existing account
      var email = document.getElementById("emailreauth").value;
      var pass = document.getElementById("passreauth").value;
      // noinspection JSUnresolvedFunction
      firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function (error) {
          //Handle errors here
          let errorCode = error.code;
          let errorMessage = error.MESSAGE;
          console.log(errorCode);
          console.log(errorMessage);
      });
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--suppress HtmlRequiredLangAttribute -->
       <html>
    <head>
        
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.6/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "hmcalreac",
    authDomain: "kbckyc",
    databaseURL: "https://abc.dmc",
    projectId: "test12d",
    storageBucket: "t11",
    messagingSenderId: "11"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
</script>


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Project Cross Comm!</title>
        
    </head>
    <body>
    <button id="accountcreate" onclick="showAccCreate()">Create your account here!</button>
    <button id="showsignin" onclick="showsignin()">Already have an account?</button>
    <button2 id="googlesignin" onclick="googlesignin()">Sign in with Google</button2>

        <h1>Project Cross Comm!</h1>
        <h2 id="subtitle">
        Welcome to <strong>Project Cross Comm!</strong>
        </h2>
        <img height="200px" src="https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/mobile/000/013/564/doge.jpg" width="260px" alt="If you can't see this image you're a pleb">
        <h2></h2>
        <p id="desc"> Project Cross Comm is a free to use chatting program that runs in your browser. All the chats are encrypted, so no one can read your chats. Enjoy the program and chat away.</p>
        <div id="hiddenaccountcreation">
            
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Account Creation</legend> <!--Create account via email sign-in-->
                    <p>
                        <label for="usernameinput">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="usernameinput" name="createUsername" placeholder="Username">
                    <p>
                        <label for="emailinput">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="emailinput" value="" placeholder="example@example.com" name="createEmail">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="passinput">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="passinput" value="" placeholder="password" name="createPass">
                    </p>
                    <button id="submit" onclick="submitAcc()">SUBMIT TO CREATE ACCOUNT </button>
                </fieldset>
            
        </div>
        <div id="hiddensignin">
            
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Sign In</legend>
                    <p>
                        <label for="usernamereauth">Username</label>
                        <input type="text" id="usernamereauth" value="">
                    <p>
                        <label for="emailreauth">Email</label>
                        <input type="email" id="emailreauth" value="">
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <label for="passreauth">Password</label>
                        <input type="password" id="passreauth" value="">
                    </p>
                    <button id="signin" onclick="signInUser()">SUBMIT To Signin to console</button>
                </fieldset>
            
        </div>

        <button id=mystat onclick="status()">CLICK me to GET Status</button>

        <button id=mystat onclick="logout()">CLICK me to logout </button>
       
        
        <div id="getthisblockoutofmygoddamnedway"> <!--Problematic code block that another member of my team put there -->
            <a style = "color: white; "id="link" href="InfoPage.html">Click here for more information.</a>
            <h6></h6>
            <a style = "color: white; "id="link2" href="ChatLayout.html">Click Here To Chat</a>
            <h6></h6>
            <a style = "color: white; "id="link3" href="https://app.termly.io/document/privacy-policy/0ae020d8-ee05-4202-a0c7-d4ff19e8f661">Privacy Policy </a>

        </div>
        <script src="ne2.js" rel="script"></script>
    </body>


    <footer>
        <p id="debugtest" class="debug">Haven't Been Signed In Yet</p>
        <noscript>Man, sucks for you! We only support modern, functioning browsers. Maybe you should get JavaScript </noscript>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment regarding the uid, however removing the space in the function parameter still does not work either on my local copy or the one running on the public debug server.

Comment: Try my code and tell me if its working or not . It was working for me. If my code works with your api key and details there’s something wrong with your rest of the code

Comment: Changed my code to fetch uid of the current user. You can refer to my before edit which has HTML included as well. Right now i just modified it to the question

Answer (score 2):

Can you please try this? This works in my case.

```
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(response => {
            const uid = response.user.uid;   // you have uid
            response.user.getIdToken()
                .then(token => {
                    // do anything with token
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    // any error handling
                })
        })
        .catch(error => {
           // any error handling
        })
```

Comment: This does not work for me. I'm beginning to think that my API keys or something must be set up improperly, because this looks like it should work.